# Using Response.BinaryWrite on button click

Tags: pdf-generation

I have a button click event and in it am calling this method to generate pdf. This works fine the first time i click on the button but it does not work if i click on the button again to do the opeartion again.  Thanks.

```
 private void CreatePDF(Customer c)
    {
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf;");
        Response.BinaryWrite(GetPrintableCustomer(c));
        Response.End();
    }
```